# Create url in myhost using Java

Tags: java, jquery, html

I am looking for create a new URL in my existing website. For example, I have my website (mywebsite.com). I just want to create a new URL link from Java like (mywebsite.com/hello). like the below fiddle html page.

http://jsfiddle.net/WRrH9/5/

This page is not existing and getting 404 in my website. I just want to create this new page from Java code.

I am trying the following code, but its not making url.

```
    public class URLTest {

        public static void main( String[] args ) {

            try {
            String data = "Welcome to the world";

                URL u1 = new URL("http://mywebsite.com/hello");
                URLConnection uc1 = u1.openConnection();

                uc1.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(uc1.getOutputStream());
                out.write(data);
                out.flush();
            }
            catch( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

can anyone say what I am missing here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the  language/technology did you use to create your website ? for example PHP, Servlets & JSP...

Comment: That website is my project only. From this only I need to create this URL.

Comment: let me get this straight, if you try to open this URL `http://mywebsite.com` from your browser what do you get ?

Comment: my java project, which is already working in local and accessed as localhost:8080/myApp

Comment: which brings us back to the first question. What is the language/technology did you use to create your website ? for example PHP, Servlets & JSP...

Comment: This is deployed in cloud and while hit mywebsite.com this index page appears. I also looking for making new web page as I told.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97830/discussion-between-quakecore-and-ratwanska).

Comment: Is there any solutuion for this?